# How to desaturate canvas group in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, shader

How to get access to custom canvas group shader? I need to desaturate all child of game object situated on canvas. Something like canvas group component that provide possibility to change alpha of all child objets.

Comment: I have tried to find canvas group sources to avoid manual set of same shader to all child objects. Imo they using more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unity might be using a more elegant solution by hiding their implementation of setting the alpha via the *CanvasGroup* component in their C++ part of the engine.

For now it looks like there is no other way than to set the material property on all UI elements (*UnityEngine.UI.Graphic*) with a custom material.

Remember, you can download the official shader source files. ;) There's a default UI shader, which you need to modify to add additional color functionality.